# Looking to build a new desktop machine

Tags: hardware

I'm in need of a new desktop machine for both work and play. I'll be running a few VBox instances at once and would like to have multiple monitors connected to this machine to support these instances. The goal is to have 4 monitors so I can run these instances and view them at the same time (still need the money for this but it is my goal hahaha). Rather then just tossing money around and hoping I'd like to start doing some research now on hardware. Where should I look to get a good idea which items are compatible with Ubuntu and fully support the OS? In the past I was building more for Windows and would run Ubuntu in an image but now I an finally be done with Windows and really want to build this machine solely for Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 0):

Intel Provides an as-is linux compatibility lists for **SOME** motherboards.

**List For Intel Desktop Boards:**

Step #1 = http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/dsktpboards

Step #2 = Choose A Board

Step #3 = Under "Compatibility" choose supported operating systems. [Usually there are several charts, the first is windows only the second is windows and linux testing]

**Intel Server/Workstation Boards:**

Step #1 = http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/server

Step #2 = Scroll down to "Sever Motherboards"

Step #3 = Choose A Board

Step #4 = Under "Compatibility" choose "Tested Operating Systems" [Depending which board you've selected there may be little or no testing, while others have a fair bit]